# Removing y-axis end ticks with tickSizeOuter(0) is not working

Tags: d3.js

[image]

(i) I am trying to remove y-axis end ticks but `tickSizeOuter(0)` is not helping me in that case.

(ii) Also I would like to have some padding after y-axis end-tick value(60), similar to as in x-axis. I tried `padding` and `paddingOuter` but that doesn't help me.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n1ueun?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

And this is my code:

```
maxAllowed = 60;
  graphData = [
    {
      hrCount: 4,
      resCount: 2
    },
    {
      hrCount: 8,
      resCount: 5
    },
    {
      hrCount: 12,
      resCount: 10
    },
    ...
const margin = { top: 25, right: 25, bottom: 25, left: 25 };
    const width =
      document.getElementById("svgcontainer").parentElement.offsetWidth -
      (margin.left + margin.right);
    const height =
      document.getElementById("svgcontainer").parentElement.offsetHeight -
      (margin.top + margin.bottom);

    // Remove any existing SVG
    d3.select("#svgcontainer")
      .selectAll("svg > *")
      .remove();

    // Group
    const g = d3
      .select("#svgcontainer")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");

    // Scale
    // x-scale
    const xScale = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(this.graphData.map((d: any) => d.hrCount))
      .range([0, width]);
    // y-scale
    const yScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, this.maxAllowed])
      .range([height, 0]);

    // y-axis gridline
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y-axis-grid")
      .call(
        d3
          .axisLeft(yScale)
          .tickSize(-width)
          .tickFormat("")
          .ticks(5)
      );

    // Axis
    // x-axis
    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSizeOuter(0);
    g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
      .attr("class", "graph-axis")
      .call(xAxis.scale(xScale))
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("font", "10px sans-serif")
      .attr("letter-spacing", "1px")
      .attr("fill", "#8997b1")
      .text("Hours");
    // y-axis
    const yAxis = d3
      .axisLeft(yScale)
      .ticks(5)
      .tickSizeOuter(0);
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "graph-axis")
      .call(yAxis.scale(yScale))
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("font", "10px sans-serif")
      .attr("letter-spacing", "1px")
      .attr("fill", "#8997b1")
      .text("Resources");

    // Data line
    const line = d3
      .line()
      .x((d: any) => xScale(d.hrCount))
      .y((d: any) => yScale(d.resCount));
    const path = g
      .append("path")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "#088dda")
      .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
      .attr("d", line(this.graphData));
    // Transition
    const totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
    path
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength);
    path
      .transition()
      .duration(4000)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

    // Data dots
    g.selectAll("line-circle")
      .data(this.graphData)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4)
      .attr("fill", "#088dda")
      .attr("cx", (d: any) => xScale(d.hrCount))
      .attr("cy", (d: any) => yScale(d.resCount));
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by removing y-axis end ticks ? Do you want to remove the tick line or the tick value as well ?

Comment: @Prince I want to remove the tick line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked your code and came up with the following approach to resolve your issue.

You can add the top padding to your chart by mapping your y axis domain to largest values present in data + some padding height (I have taken 5).
Changes Required to do so:

```
maxAllowed = 0;

this.maxAllowed = d3.max(this.graphData, d => d.hrCount) + 5; // max value + padding

// y-scale
const yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, this.maxAllowed])
  .range([height, 0]);
```

For the second change where you want to remove the outermost tickSize, you can easily accomplish it using `.tickSizeOuter(0);` The issue is you are not able to see this change because tickSizeOuter makes zero value for those tick line which does not have corresponding y-tick value as well (The end point of y axis has some tick y value).

But if you mark the value of `this.maxAllowed = 65` and remove the `tickSizeOuter(0)` then you will be able to see that the end of y axis which has no y-tick value but its tick line is extended outwards. In these cases we uses `tickSizeOuter(0)` to remove the tick line.

And IMO you should only use this and should not remove the tick line for 0 value. It can lead to unnecessary results. But if you still want to remove tick line for 0 value. You can use the below code and remove it from the svg:

```
d3.selectAll(".y-axes-tick .tick line").each(function(d, i) {
  debugger;
  if (i === 0) {
    this.remove();
  }
});
```

Please find here the [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lx4vdu)

Answer (score 0):

You customize your axis on the call.  It should look something like this:

```
.call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSizeOuter(0)
```

Right now, you are trying to customize it when creating the scale for the visual.
As far as padding, I think the function you are looking for is tickPadding().

[Here's some documentation from d3.js on customizing the axis.](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis)